# How to connect to GCP BigTable using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am connecting to my GCP BigTable instance using python (google-cloud-bigtable library), after setting up "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in my environment variables. I'm successful at doing this.

However, my requirement is that I want to pass the *credentials* during the run-time while creating the BigTable Client object as shown below:

```
client = bigtable.Client(credentials='82309281204023049', project='xjkejfkx')
```

I have followed the [GCP BigTable Client Documentation](https://gcloud-python-bigtable.readthedocs.io/en/0.0.1/client.html) to connect to GCP BigTable, but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/testingonlyinformix/bigtable.py", line 14, in <module>
    client = bigtable.Client(credentials="9876543467898765", project="xjksjkdn", admin=True)
  File "D:\testingonlyinformix\new_venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigtable\client.py", line 196, in __init__
    project=project, credentials=credentials, client_options=client_options,
  File "D:\testingonlyinformix\new_venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\client\__init__.py", line 320, in __init__
    self, credentials=credentials, client_options=client_options, _http=_http
  File "D:\testingonlyinformix\new_venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\client\__init__.py", line 167, in __init__
    raise ValueError(_GOOGLE_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_HELP)
ValueError: This library only supports credentials from google-auth-library-python. See https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for help on authentication with this library.
```

Can someone please suggest what are all the *fields/attributes* a `Client` object is expecting during the run-time when making a connection to GCP BigTable?

Thanks

Comment: As mentioned in the above error message. Did you try to add google-auth-library-python?  And performed authentication through that library function?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty for the record we have the library google-auth already installed, can you please help me understand how do we pass the credentials to BigTable using google-auth in the program ? Thanks

Comment: Also as you mentioned I checked the documentation but they say that OAuth is being deprecated et cetera, I am stumped and not able to find another way to connect other than defining "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in environment variables :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 hrs of searching I finally landed on these page(s), please check them out in order:

1. [BigTable Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/authentication)
2. [Using end-user authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user)
3. [OAuth Scopes for BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/oauth-scopes)

```
from google_auth_oauthlib import flow

appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    "client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.admin"])

appflow.run_console()
credentials = appflow.credentials
```

The `credentials` in the previous step will need to be provided to the BigTable **client** object:

> client = bigtable.Client(credentials=credentials, project='xjkejfkx')

This solution worked for me, if anyone has any other suggestions, please do pitch-in.